# Почему ко всем применяется только последний hover?

Tags: html, css

```
.mak_menu a, a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mak_menu a:hover
{
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.mak_footer a, a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mak_footer a:hover
{
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<table>
<tr>
<td class="mak_menu">
<div>
<a href=''>Ссылка1</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="mak_footer">
<div>
<a href=''>Ссылка2</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ссылка 1 ведёт себя так же, как Ссылка2 не смотря на то, что у них разные стили
(Любителей править приглашаю сделать заголовок вопроса более грамотным :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот селектор:

```
.mak_menu a, a:link, a:visited
```

Вы понимаете как три селектора:

```
1) .mak_menu a
2) .mak_menu a:link
3) .mak_menu a:visited
```

Браузер понимает как три отдельных:

```
1) .mak_menu a
2) a:link
3) a:visited
```

Тоесть второй и третий работают не так, как думаете вы. Чтобы исправить проблему, нужно заменить селекторы на те, которые показаны в первом блоке. Также, советую почитать подробнее о селекторах `css` и [проверить знания](http://htmlbook.ru/test/selector).